# How to transform the schema into columns in Java Structured Streaming?

Tags: java, apache-spark, schema, spark-structured-streaming

I have a dataset with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- schema_version: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- countries: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- country_name: binary (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- cities: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- city_name: binary (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- city_population: long (nullable = true)
```

How do I access or transform the data within the schema such I have in the end following dataframe

```
 | country_name | city_name | population |
 -----------------------------------------
 |              |           |            |
 |              |           |            |
 |              |           |            |
```

How do I manage the arrays within the schema?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is just:

```
originalDf.select(explode($"countries").as("explode_countries"))
          .select(explode($"explode_countries.cities").as("explode_cities"))
          .select($"explode_countries.country_name".as("country_name"), 
                  $"explode_cities.city_name".as("city_name"), 
                  $"explode_cities.city_population".as("population"))
```